# Running Python code without arguments when arguments are expected

Tags: python, shell, terminal, arguments

I am trying to write a python code that will be executed in a shell with arguments such as:

```
python programName.py arg1 arg2
```

I have to write the code so that if no arguments are passed it will default to default values that are declared in the code. I tried doing this by using something similar to:

```
# ... Imports such as sys
x = argv[0]
y = argv[1]
#  ... Other Code

def main():
 if x is None:
  x = 0
 if y is None:
  y = 12
# ... Other Code
```

But Python did not like my way of doing it, and it would throw an error when no arguments are passed.

Sorry I can't show the error because the program is on my other computer that is not with me. What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't exactly match your requirements, but I think argparse is the best way to deal with arguments in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys

# ... Imports such as sys
x = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None  # None is the default value
y = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else None  # None is the default value
#  ... Other Code
```

`sys.argv[0]` -> gives the program file name

In the above question you're running `python program_file_name x y`, in this case `sys.argv[0]` gives you the `program_file_name`.

Comment: No `IndexError` and `UnboundLocalError`?

Comment: In the above question he's running python program_file_name x y
in this case sys.argv[0] gives you the program_file_name

Comment: I mean seems like OP want to check if there is no `arg2`, then set `y`  as `12`. But if there is really no `arg2` then `y = sys.argv[2]` will raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: And the function will raise a `UnboundLocalError` here because `x` or `y` is a global variable here, but you're not using `global x, y`.

Comment: He can modify the logical part to what it suits for him, the actual problem was in the way he was accessing the arguments, which is corrected in the above answer

Comment: But OP asked: *I have to write the code so that if no arguments are passed it will default to default values that are declared in the code.* So the real problem isn't about neither `sys.argv or argv` nor `sys.argv[0 or 1]`.

Comment: added the entire logik

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length of `argv`:

```
if len(argv) < 2:
    x = 0
if len(argv) < 3:
    y = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the following. You need to check the length of the argument list to determine, the no. of arguments passed.

```
import sys

x = None
y = None

if len(sys.argv) > 3:
   print("Usage: ....")
   sys.exit(1)

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
   x = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
   y = sys.argv[2]
```

Comment: I feel like you're giving yourself more trouble than its worth doing it that way, why not systematically check and build your x and y values, eg, you have

if len(sys.argv) == 2: x = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) == 3: y = sys.argv[2]

.... etc